# How to use subscription of GraphQL in Graphql.js

Tags: node.js, graphql, relayjs, graphql-js, relay

I am using [relay-fullstack](https://github.com/lvarayut/relay-fullstack). It's using `GraphQL.js`. I want use subscription of GraphQL in `GraphQL.js`. But I can't find documents about subscription of GraphQL in [GraphQL.js](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/).
Can I use subscription of GraphQL in `GraphQL.js`?
Or does not it support that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! I created a simple repository based on Facebook relay-examples todo relay modern with subscriptions support (server and client), you can check it out, I might also improve it in the future: https://github.com/jeremy-colin/relay-examples-subscription